# Are stored procedures and triggers the same in Sql Server and MySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-server-2005, phpmyadmin

I have two stored procedures and one trigger for a class I am taking that are done in sql server 2005.  I want to recreate them in mysql with phpmyadmin.  Everytime i put them in I get a 1064 error.  Is this becuase phpmyadmin does not handle stored procedures or triggers well, or is it becuase the syntax from sql server 2005 to mysql is very different?  If it is this, then where could i go online to learn the correct syntax to write my stored procedures and triggers in mysql/phpmyadmin... or should I just pick up a book at barnes and nobles?  This is my senior project.

Comment: May we take a look at the code? Can you post an URL or paste it in (provided it is not > ca. 40 lines of code... )

Answer (score 1):

The syntax and feature sets in MySQL will be slightly different, but the concepts and usage patterns and design motivations will be very similar if not identical.  I suggest reading up in the MySQL manuals before buying any books:

[Triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html)

[Stored Procedures](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-routines.html)

So you can definitely port your T-SQL code to MySQL's SQL dialect.

Comment: Thank you!  I was jus unsure if it was becuase of the software or t-sql problems.

Comment: @user314877: There might be idioms in T-SQL that are a challenge to transcribe, but flow control and the like should come over easily.

Answer (score 0):

It's because MySQL does not support Transact-SQL, which is the SQL variant Sybase and MSSQLServer use to program triggers and stored procedures.

So, the answer to your question is: **NO**.

Comment: So if i want to make these procedures and triggers work... am i not able to at all?

Comment: Not without some testing and modifications.